# Why doesn't QueryService get called for IHttpSecurity when using TEmbeddedWB?

Tags: delphi, tembeddedwb

`TEmbeddedWB` contains an event for extending support for additional services, called `OnQueryService`. According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775049(v=vs.85).aspx), this function will be called to allow me to return an `IHttpSecurity` reference, so I can handle certificate errors my way. However, while `OnQueryService` is called for a number of other interfaces, it never gets called for `IHttpSecurity`.

Sample code:

```
unit InsecureBrowser;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows,
  Winapi.Messages,
  Winapi.Urlmon,
  Winapi.WinInet,
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Variants,
  System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls,
  Vcl.Forms,
  Vcl.Dialogs,
  Vcl.OleCtrls,
  Vcl.StdCtrls,
  SHDocVw_EWB,
  EwbCore,
  EmbeddedWB;

type
  TInsecureBrowserForm = class(TForm, IHttpSecurity, IWindowForBindingUI)
    web: TEmbeddedWB;
    cmdGoInsecure: TButton;
    procedure webQueryService(Sender: TObject; const [Ref] rsid,
      iid: TGUID; var Obj: IInterface);
    procedure cmdGoInsecureClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { IWindowForBindingUI }
    function GetWindow(const guidReason: TGUID; out hwnd): HRESULT; stdcall;

    { IHttpSecurity }
    function OnSecurityProblem(dwProblem: Cardinal): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;

var
  InsecureBrowserForm: TInsecureBrowserForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function TInsecureBrowserForm.GetWindow(const guidReason: TGUID;
  out hwnd): HRESULT;
begin
  Result := S_FALSE;
end;

function TInsecureBrowserForm.OnSecurityProblem(dwProblem: Cardinal): HRESULT;
begin
  if (dwProblem = ERROR_INTERNET_INVALID_CA) or
     (dwProblem = ERROR_INTERNET_SEC_CERT_CN_INVALID)
    then Result := S_OK
    else Result := E_ABORT;
end;

procedure TInsecureBrowserForm.webQueryService(Sender: TObject;
  const [Ref] rsid, iid: TGUID; var Obj: IInterface);
begin
  if IsEqualGUID(IID_IWindowForBindingUI, iid) then
    Obj := Self as IWindowForBindingUI
  else if IsEqualGUID(IID_IHttpSecurity, iid) then
    Obj := Self as IHttpSecurity;
end;

procedure TInsecureBrowserForm.cmdGoInsecureClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  web.Navigate('https://evil.intranet.site');
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not obvious, but it turns out you need to navigate to `about:blank` before using `WebBrowser2`, or certain things just don't happen, including some `QueryService` calls. Thanks to Igor Tandetnik for identifying this [in 2010](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d9e03b5d-a145-417a-8c43-4371ab6bf0f2/ihttpsecuritygetwindow-is-crashing-when-trying-to-handle-certificate-errors?forum=vcmfcatl).

So, just add:

```
procedure TInsecureBrowserForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  web.Navigate('about:blank');
end;
```

I also wrote this up on my blog: https://marc.durdin.net/2016/03/dont-forget-to-navigate-to-aboutblank-when-embedding-iwebbrowser2/