# Bypass self signed certificates in web browser using IHTTPSecurity

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

I have researched all I can on implementing the `IHTTPSECURITY` interface with Delphi `TWebBrowser`. I am trying to navigate to a site via https. The site has a self signed certificate. I wish to avoid the security warnings popping up/appearing in the browser.

If I switch `silent` mode to true for the browser the security dialog no longer pops up, but the browser automatically selects "No" as the answer to the question "Do you want to Proceed"?.

I believe the way around this is via the IHTTPSecurity interface. I have found code to implement this for EmbeddedWB ([why-doesnt-queryservice-get-called-for-ihttpsecurity-when-using-tembeddedwb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36031974/why-doesnt-queryservice-get-called-for-ihttpsecurity-when-using-tembeddedwb)). I have tried to implement this for `TWebBrowser`, but the `onSecurityProblem` function does not fire. My code is below:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.OleCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls, SHDocVw, ActiveX, Winapi.Urlmon, Winapi.WinInet;

  type TWebBrowser = class(SHDocVw.TWebBrowser, IHTTPSecurity, IWindowForBindingUI)
  private
    function GetWindow(const guidReason: TGUID; out hwnd): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function OnSecurityProblem(dwProblem: Cardinal): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;


type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    WebBrowser1: TWebBrowser;
    Button1: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses System.NetEncoding;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  var
    Flags, TargetFrameName, PostData, headers, url:OleVariant;
    authenticate:string;
begin
  webBrowser1.Navigate('about:blank');
  Flags := '1';
  TargetFrameName := '';
  PostData := '';

  Authenticate := TNetEncoding.Base64.Encode('MediaUser:test');
  Headers:='Authorization: Basic '+Authenticate;
  webBrowser1.Navigate(Edit1.text, flags, TargetFrameName, PostData, headers);
end;

function TWebBrowser.GetWindow(const guidReason: TGUID;
  out hwnd): HRESULT;
begin
  Result := S_FALSE;
end;


function TWebBrowser.OnSecurityProblem(dwProblem: Cardinal): HRESULT;
begin
  if (dwProblem = ERROR_INTERNET_INVALID_CA) or
     (dwProblem = ERROR_INTERNET_SEC_CERT_CN_INVALID)
    then Result := S_OK
    else Result := E_ABORT;
end;

end.
```

What am I doing wrong?

As a side issue, when the above app terminates I get an unspecified `EoleException`.

Comment: You may need to use Cef4Delphi as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48554936/delphi-cef4-chromium-do-not-show-web-sites-with-secure-connection-error

Comment: Just checked out Cef4Delphi and it describes itself as a project to embed Chromium based browsers in Delphi. I don't really want to go down that route. I believe it should be possible to do what I want to do with `TWebBrowser` using `IHTTPSecurity`, but I am using it incorrectly it seems.